# How to configure FQDN (fully qualified domain names) to ESXi host and vCenter Server?

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi, vcenter, fqdn

I am unable to configure the fully qualified domain names for ESXi hosts and vCenter Server. Now we are using the IPs for connecting to both of them .Instead of the IP we want to have domain names. Tried exploring and found something called active directory, which is used
with the domain names instead of IPs. We don't know how to setup DNS server in vCenter Server. Please suggest the proper way to get it done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question several time, I finally understand that you want to be able to access your esxi and vcenter with their names ?

You don't necessarily need a DNS for that.

Depending on your client system, and if you are an administrator of said system, you can directly add the name and IP to a local hosts file.

In Linux, it's /etc/hosts

In Windows, it's %windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

You edit those files and add lines of the type:

10.1.2.3        myesxi.local

10.1.2.4        myvcenter.local

And then, you should be able to access your machines with "myesxi.local" and "myvcenter.local" without typing the ip